# Fraud detection on hotmail from Simplenews Newsletter

Tags: 7, emails

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website using Simplenews newsletter module.
But when a user has hotmail, the mail comes with a flag "Be careful. This sender is not approved by our controls for fraud detection."
I googled this and I saw that it has to do something with SPF but I don't understand what this is and what steps do I have to do to fix this issue.
Is there an option from administrator or a line of code I can use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps you can also carry out by looking here [How can I prevent my mail from being classified as spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-can-i-prevent-my-mail-from-being-classified-as-spam). It includes setting up Domain Keys, SPF etc.

You can also refer to some steps for Microsoft here [How to prevent email sent from drupal from going into spam box](https://www.drupal.org/node/869518#comment-3269282).

Answer (score 0):

It comes from your host. If it has been used for spam before, there's not much you can easily do.

I highlight "easily".

Set up smtp with Google for $5/month and save yourself the heartache.